# Android NDK, how to pass Context to native code? What type to use?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am newbie in JNI. In my android project, I have a java class which declares a native function:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
     …

     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
         …
         doIt(getApplicationContext(), "test");
     }


     public native boolean doIt(Context context, String name);

     static
     {
           System.loadLibrary("myNativelib");
     }

}
```

As you see above, I want the native function takes two parameters, one is `Context` of Android app, one is `String`.

In JNI native code, I know that for java `String`, I should use type `jString`, but how to pass the context to my native code then?

I need `Context` type in my native code, because my native code will later calls java code with `context` as parameter.

Comment: While it might be possible to figure out the answer from the candidate duplicate question, it's actually not asking the same thing, and doesn't really provide anywhere as clearly and directly applicable a solution as Alex Barker's "Its just a Java object so jobject will work fine." answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Its just a Java object so jobject will work fine.  You will need to look up the class and methods to use it.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_yourclass_yourNativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject obj) {
        jclass Context_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/content/Context");
        jmethodID Check_id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, Context_class, "checkCallingOrSelfPermission", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

        jint i = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj, Check_id, (*env)->NewStringUTF("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"));
}
```

Comment: But how to get a context? What I need is a way to get a context. I understand that with your answer I can find Context class and call its method. But your code just showed CallIntMethod, how to call method to get a context then????

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that you were passing the Context to your native method.  That's what your example suggested with: public native boolean doIt(Context context, String name) which would produce the method signature JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_MyService_doIt(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject context, jstring name);  I am not familiar with how you would acquire a Context object using Java.  The general idea would be to call getApplicationContext() on the jobject that provides that method.